# Conics equation formula?

Tags: geometry

What is the conics formula? I resaerched it but I cannot find it properly. There are lots of different results. Please say it to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For *fixed* real numbers $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f$, the conics have equations:

$$ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f=0$$

- If $c^2-4ab <0$ then the conic is an ellipse.
- If $c^2-4ab=0$ then the conic is a parabola.
- If $c^2-4ab>0$ then the conic is a hyperbola.

Comment: Thanks, I deliberately did not write down the exact cases, because I wasn't sure and didn't bother to look up...

Answer (score 2):

$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ is one I know. The discriminant is $B^2-4AC$ and when it is zero, it is a (rotated) parabola. If the discriminant is nonzero, then it is an ellipse or hyperbola

Comment: Well, $B=0$ is this possible?

Comment: I found such equation  $Ay^2-Bx^2-F=0 $ what is this? Can I say it is conics?

Comment: Sure, why not? B is a coefficient responsible for some rotation. If B=0, it is still a conic section

Comment: Yes, $Ay^2-Bx^2=c$ is also a conic section, assuming that the coefficients are not zero here. If B is negative and c is positive, you have an ellipse, for example

Comment: Thank you so much. Nearly during 1hour, I thought this. You helped me so much. Thanks a lot:))

Comment: ok, you're welcome, don't forget to look at the cases of the discriminant, stated by Fly

Comment: Okay thanks a lot:)